# Is there any way to deploy multiple projects using the same app service in Release management?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Implementing CI/CD process to my current project. we are using VSTS and deploying our app into Azure platform.

I have a look at below azure documentation.To deploy each project, we have to create each web app task in the release management.

[Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/howto-webdeploy-webapps?view=vsts#multipleapps)

Below is my project solution.

**Project structure**

[image]

Under feature folder, Each folder is basically a web application project. To deploy into Azure we app service, we have to create each web app task.

Is that possible that i can deploy all web projects using a single web app task in release management. If team adds any new projects, again i have to do changes across all enviroments in pipelines.

Please suggest better approach.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the built-in task to deploy multiple web apps to Azure app services, the easy way is adding multiple Web App deploy tasks for each web app.

You can refer to the [source code of Web App Deployment task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment) to custom build/task through VSTS extension to meet your requirement: [Add a build or release task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts).